# Javascript Pullup Menu

Tags: javascript

At the bottom of my website I am going to have a pullup menu division for an instant chat. I am using Javascript to pullup the menu.

I have a tab with id 'chatTab' and the actual chat messages go in the id 'chat'. The chat tab rests at the bottom of the page until you click it, and then it pulls up along with the chat. The problem is, it will not pull up. I have used the onClick method with my tab division and confirm that it works, so the problem is somewhere in the JS.

```
var current;
var pullChat = 0;
var pullMenu = function() {
    if(pullChat === 0) {
        current = document.getElementById('chatTab');
        current.style.bottom = '300';
        alert('pie');
        current = document.getElementById('chat');
        current.style.bottom = '0'; //starts at -300
    }
}
```

The alert message is something I do to test if a line of code runs, in which this case it does run.

My HTML is long but these are the two important things:

```
<div id='chatTab' onClick='pullMenu()'>Instant Chat</div>
<div id='chat'></div>
```

Here is the CSS for the important items:

```
#chatTab {
    z-index:1000;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    background-color:#FF9933;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:1.8em;
}
#chatTab:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}
#chat {
    z-index:1001;
    position:fixed;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    bottom:-300px;
    height:300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you include the necessary HTML markup as well?

Comment: Okay I added the two important things. The rest of the HTML is nothing related to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS `bottom` property expects a length value. `300` is not a length. It isn't `0` and it doesn't have a unit.

You probably mean `'300px'`.

Comment: How did I not see that! Thanks.

Comment: @turkey3 If this solved your problem mark it as the right answer.

Comment: I can't I need a better reputation